# What formula would you use to add up a column based on results from two drop down menus?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to calculate a column based on selections from two other columns with drop down menus.

For example :

In one column, "C" you have 3 options (A team,B team,C team), In column "F" you have the day of week to schedule (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday) and in Column "E" I would like to put how many minutes total each line is.

This will calculate how many minutes worth A team has on Monday.

I have been successful using SUMIFS code to narrow by the first set of criteria

i.e. =SUMIFS(E2:E20,C2:C20,"A team")

When I try to add a second set of criteria, it doesn't work.

How can I achieve my goal here? Should I be trying something different?

I have tried just adding the criteria like so:

=SUMIFS(E2:E20,C2:C20,"A team",F2:F20,"Monday") ....... but it wont work!

Thanks,

Tyler

Comment: @Scott, the question to which you are referring was also asked by Tyler, so I assume the answer did not work and I think that I see why. @Tyler, from this question it seems like you want the formula to put values in cells E2:E20, is that correct? If so you'll need to change the first argument ("Sum Range") to the column that the values come from. The first example of Excel Help on the `SUMIFS` function should help you to understand what "Sum Range" should point to. If you need more assistance it would be helpful if you could include a screen shot of at least part of your data.

Comment: Please do not repost your question if you do not get a useful answer right away. If an answer you receive does not work for you, you may indicate that in a comment on the answer. That way, the person who answered may be able to help you, or someone may see that you are still looking for help and post a separate, better answer. FYI, this question will be closed as a duplicate to your first question and possibly be deleted. In the meantime, feel free to take a [tour](http://superuser.com/tour) of the site to learn how Super User works.

Comment: @Clif, removed my comment

Answer (score 1):

one way you might do it is as follows:

Insert a new column wherever appropriate (it will be hidden afterwards). Suppose you put it in column G. In these cells concatenate Column C and F, for example in G2, =CONCATENATE(C2,F2).

Then your sumifs formula should be =SUMIFS(E2:E20,G2:G20,"A teamMonday").

You can now hide column G.

---

As a side note, you can of course use concatenate inside your SUMIFS, eg

A1: B team

A2: Friday

A3: =SUMIFS(E2:E20,C2:C20,CONCATENATE(A1,A2)).

Good luck.